# Stop app from pausing music (from Spotify etc.) on launch?

Tags: java, android, audio, background, splash-screen

I'm busy making a template for a general UI which I can use in multiple apps, and I discovered that my app pauses music playing in the background whenever it is launched - most likely due to it having its own start-up sound in the form of a .mp4 that is played as a splash screen.

Is there a way of preventing my app prioritizing its own volume above others or making it mute its own volume when sound is already being played by the device?

PS: If using .mp4 is not general practice for splash screens, I admit, I'm learning as I go - if anyone can correct me on the proper or most optimized solution for making a sound + video happen while not interfering with external apps' sound, that would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know of is disabling the sound for the app that is causing the issue. Most apps have a setting to turn off sound. I don't think you can disable this for every app at once, otherwise when someone calls, you would have to manually turn off the music before answering, "hello".

You can also go into your app settings and "stop notifications" which might help.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Spotify on my s10 for some times. I also faced the same issue. I found a post [why Spotify keeps stopping](https://droidtheory.com/spotify-stops-playing-songs/), and I cleared cache and turned off power saving mode on my device. You can try logging out from other devices which is also helpful